# Hey Google vs OK Google

Tags: google-assistant

Is there any way to use "Hey Google" instead of "OK Google" on my Motorola Z2 Play?

On my old phone Huawei P8 Lite from 2015 running android 6.0 i was able to use "Hey Google" instead of "OK Google"

I remember at some point when i clicked retrain voice model i was offered to say both "OK Google" and "Hey Google"

But on my new phone running android 7.1.1 no matter how many times i click retrain voice model it just keeps offering me to say "OK Google" 3 times.

I have all the latest software updates for my phone, and the latest available version of the Google app.
It is frustrating to see this option on much older phones, what am doing wrong here?

"OK Google" is very awkward for me especially after getting used to saying "Hey Google" on my 3 year old junk phone.

I tried asking this on the Google support site but they didn't read my question and just copy pasted the same response they give to everyone who reports any issue with Google Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

"Hey Google" should work on MM devices.
You can install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googleassistant app if you're unable to set 'Hey Google' from main Google app.

Comment: Thank you for the response, sadly the app you linked is "not available in my country"